# (Groovy/Java) Inheriting annotations to inner classes

Tags: java, inheritance, groovy, annotations, boilerplate

I have a bunch of classes, which in turn contain many inner/nested classes, that need annotations for deserialization (@JsonIgnoreProperties) and for reducing Equals overriding boilerplate (@EqualsAndHashCode, Groovy default API, not Lombok).

My code looks like this:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@EqualsAndHashCode(includeFields = true)
class SomeClass {
    String id


    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    @EqualsAndHashCode(includeFields = true)
    class InnerOne {
        String foo
    }

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    @EqualsAndHashCode(includeFields = true)
    class InnerTwo {
        String bar
    }

    // and so on...

}
```

Both those annotations belong to third party libraries and are not marked as @Inherited, hence I'm forced to repeat them in each inner class.

Is there a way to reduce that boilerplate?

Answer (score 0):

The author of the annotation processor has decided whether it is a good idea to inherit annotations or not.

- The author might write the annotation processor to inherit annotations, so that the user has to write fewer annotations.
- The author might write the annotation processor to not inherit annotations, so that the meaning of a class is obvious by looking at the class alone, without having to read every superclass as well.

Either of these is a defensible choice.  I tend to lean toward the latter, because it improves readability, and code is read more often than it is written.

If you wish to change the behavior, you will need to modify the semantics of the annotation processor by modifying its source code.  In your case, it is probably easier to write the extra annotations.